# Is it possible to mix functionalities from various map libraries?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have a short question - is it possible at all to mix various maps' libraries functionalities? For example, I'd like to use leaflet functionalities on mapbox map e.g. drawing polygons etc. I tried once and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few plugins that should have the desired functionality in the [Plugins section](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html) of the Leaflet docs:

- [mapbox-gl-leaflet](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-leaflet) - Binding from Mapbox GL JS to the Leaflet API
- [Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile](https://github.com/SpatialServer/Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile) - A Leaflet Plugin that renders Mapbox Vector Tiles on canvas. See demo. Compatible with Leaflet 0.7.x only.

[LEAFLET PLUGINS](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html)